# how to fill another text item

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am very new in oracle forms so my mind is very very confused. I have 2 text items in the begining  and at the end of the form i have multi text item like grid view. When i push the button the system should get and add the information to the grid view but my programme is working like that. it gets the information and add the information in the first place of the grid view, when i add second information it deletes the first row and add it in the first place. it should keep the last situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for example BLOCK_NAME is your multi text item, TEXT_ITEM1 is your first text item and TEXT_ITEM2 is your second text item, you can write the following code in `when-button_pressed`:

```
go_block('BLOCK_NAME');

first_record;

:BLOCK_NAME.COLUMN1 := :TEXT_ITEM1 + :BLOCK_NAME.COLUMN1;

last_record;

:BLOCK_NAME.COLUMN1 := :TEXT_ITEM2 + :BLOCK_NAME.COLUMN1;

commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

good for two items only
if the items are more then 2 then better user these command with in loop
and use next_record instead of last record
and check for :system.last_record true
            if true then exit
else
continue working